# Password for DCP-L2540DW firmware update

Tags: passwords, printer, brother-printer

Trying to update firmware on DCP-L2540DW and it asks for password.

Looked behind the printer, there is only rectangular Serial Number sticker and manufacture date July 2014. Cannot find anything saying "PWD". No other sticker around the printer either.

Tried also printing Network Configuration and WLAN settings - no signs of password.

This is first time I am trying to update firmware, default "initpass" or "access" passwords do not work (see image below)

[image]

Comment: I've said this many times before: only ever update printer f/w if you KNOW it will fix a problem you experience (check the release docs). Or if it offers a new feature you would like, AND you believe in Santa Claus.

Comment: In my case printer is causing power surge upon booting, which trips the circuit fuse. There was a mention on the website that new firmware may have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Default "initpass" or "access" passwords do not work

> If you've created a custom password for your Brother machine's
> settings, and you've forgotten the password, you'll have to reset the
> network settings to factory default to regain access to these
> settings. We cannot help you recover a lost password.
>
> (For wireless network connection user)
>
> connected to the wireless network and reset the network settings to
> factory default, you must reconnect your Brother machine to the
> wireless network again.If your Brother machine is

Source [What is the default password for my Brother network card, BRAdmin, Remote Setup or Web Based Management? | Brother](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpl2540dw_us_as&faqid=faq00002496_002)

---

#### Reset the network settings to the factory default

> 1. Press Menu.
> 2. Press the Up or Down arrow key to display Network, and then press OK.
> 3. Press the Up or Down arrow key to display Network Reset, and then press OK.
> 4. Follow the machine's instruction to reset the network settings.

Source [Reset the network settings to the factory default | Brother](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpl2540dw_us_as&faqid=faq00000105_034)

Comment: Resetting network settings worked like a charm, after reboot the printer internal website shows option to change the password.